# SQL Server: Require multiple conditions before delete

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

When deleting rows in a certain table, I would like to only allow the delete *if* at least 2 specific columns are referenced.

For example:

```
Delete From TransTable
/* delete fails - need where condition*/

Delete From Transtable
WHERE TransID = @TransID AND UserID = @UserID
/* rows deleted */
```

My reason for doing this is to add a second layer of security to a delete process. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If either @TransID or @UserID are NULL this will delete zero rows anway. All comparisons against null evaluate to false (unknown strictly, for the inevitable pedants, but practically it is false here).

However, for more complex logic, such as throwing an error, use a stored procedure with 2 mandatory parameters and some logic. (Edit: I'd do this)

There is no way to enforce 2 conditions unless your code restricts this as above. No-one should be able to DELETE anyway directly with SQL tools or such, or bypassing your checks.

Comment: Exactly. Control data access through stored procedures, then you can easily *require* these parameters to be provided, and can also dictate valid domains for their values. If you allow ad hoc deletes from your tables, good luck!

Comment: Thanks gbn and Aaron. *I* do ad hoc deletes from tables, but maybe I cannot event be trusted! Deleting exclusively through a stored proc makes sense. I was hoping there was a way I could put a 'rule' on the table.